# How to upgrade Xubuntu

Tags: 18.04, 20.04

I would just like to know how to upgrade Xubuntu 18.04 to Xubuntu 20.04
Thank you

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am certain the answer is on this site somewhere, but really quickly first make sure all current installed apps are up-to-date before upgrading.

Check what the update-manager is set for:

```
grep Prompt /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

Make sure the return is `Prompt=lts`

Then from a terminal window type in:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Then just run the following line to upgrade your distro to the next release:

```
do-release-upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

I would always read the release notes first for you release

https://wiki.xubuntu.org/releases/20.04/release-notes

Many *flavors* don't provide upgrade instructions, because their upgrade instructions are identical to the main Ubuntu system, so they instead refer you there

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNoteshttps://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes

(Releases that use Qt, such as Kubuntu, Lubuntu tend to have different commands, as they use different options (-m) to ensure screen saver/lock screen doesn't occur)

From a text terminal you can upgrade as Terrance describes, but you'll need to ensure screensaver or power saving functions don't kick in if using a GUI or problems may occur.

If using the GUI (*including terminal on GUI*) I'd suggest using command(s) provided in the main Ubuntu release notes (they disable screensaver/power etc during upgrade process). The instructions are found in the "*Upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS or 19.10*" section.

Comment: I've avoided giving commands intentionally, as I feel it's worthwhile reading the release notes. Known issues, and work-arounds are found there, as discovered by the teams in testing, which are worth reading first for any upgrade, so should they occur (*which yes is unlikely*), you don't panic, and know where the solution (work-around) is.